# Match On Element At Any Level Using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

The XSLT below works exactly as it is supposed to when the match nodes are children of the parent.  The value in the AttributeID is used to replace the element name and the original element name is saved in a new attribute called OrgName.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <!-- identity transform -->
  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Change Values/Value value of AttributeID -->
  <xsl:template match="Values/Value|MultiValue|MetaData/Value">
    <xsl:element level="any" name="{@AttributeID}">
    <xsl:attribute name="OrgName">
      <xsl:value-of select="name()" />
    </xsl:attribute>      
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <!--empty template suppresses this attribute-->
  <xsl:template match="@AttributeID" />

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But if the match nodes are nested multiple levels (and at various levels) is there a way to match anywhere without specifically specifying the path?  I tried level="any" as well as altering the match to include the root parent but have not been successful.

```
  <xsl:template match="Values/Value|MultiValue|RootParent//MetaData/Value">
```

Any help is appreciated.  Sample data is as follows:  This is a pared down version of the original file which is quite large.  I added comments on the lines that should be altered by the XSLT.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ROOT-ProductInformation ExportTime="2017-10-02 16:24:31" ExportContext="Context1" ContextID="Context1" WorkspaceID="Main" UseContextLocale="false">
  <Classifications>
    <Classification ID="Classification 1 root" UserTypeID="Classification 1 user-type root" Selected="false">
      <Name>Classification 1 root</Name>
      <AttributeLink AttributeID="user.documentvalue" />  <!-- NOT Here -->
      <Classification ID="Application_Root_Hierarchy" UserTypeID="Application_Root" Selected="false">
        <Name>Application Hierarchy</Name>
        <Classification ID="Application_Folder" UserTypeID="Application_Folder" Selected="false">
          <Name>Applications</Name>
          <Classification ID="W" UserTypeID="Application" Selected="false" Referenced="true">
            <Name>W</Name>
            <MetaData>
              <Value AttributeID="APPLICATIONGROUP">W</Value>  <!-- Here -->
            </MetaData>
            <Classification ID="pt213996" UserTypeID="Protocol" Selected="false" Referenced="true">
              <Name>Western</Name>
                <EntityCrossReference EntityID="s214146" Type="Protocol_To_Species" />
              <MetaData>
                <Value AttributeID="PROTOCOLNO">19</Value>  <!-- Here -->
                <Value AttributeID="PROTOCOLDESCRIPTION">Western </Value>  <!-- Here -->
                <MultiValue AttributeID="PROTOCOLCOMPANIONITEMS">  <!-- Here -->
                  <Value>7720S</Value>
                  <Value>7722S</Value>
                </MultiValue>
                <Value AttributeID="APPLICATIONABBR">W</Value>  <!-- Here -->
              </MetaData>
            </Classification>
          </Classification>
        </Classification>
      </Classification>
    </Classification>
  </Classifications>
  <Entities>
    <Entity ID="t211773" UserTypeID="Target" ParentID="Target_Category" Selected="false" Referenced="true">
      <Name>Akt1</Name>
      <Values>
        <Value AttributeID="TARGETNO">T07427</Value>  <!-- Here -->
        <Value AttributeID="ACCESSION_GP">NP_005154</Value>  <!-- Here -->
        <MultiValue AttributeID="DEVSUBSECTIONS">  <!-- Here -->
          <Value>Something</Value>
        </MultiValue>
        <Value AttributeID="ORGANISM_COMMON_NAME">human</Value>  <!-- Here -->
      </Values>
    </Entity>
    <Entity ID="s214155" UserTypeID="Species" ParentID="Species_Root" Selected="false" Referenced="true">
      <Name>Hm</Name>
      <Values>
        <Value AttributeID="HOSTSPECIES_YN" ID="N">N</Value>  <!-- Here -->
      </Values>
    </Entity>
  </Entities>
  <Products>
    <Product ID="p721653" UserTypeID="Product" ParentID="Primary_Antibodies">
      <Name>DYKDDDDK</Name>
      <ProductCrossReference ProductID="KIT781787" Type="Product_To_KIT" />

      <EntityCrossReference EntityID="t353809" Type="Product_to_Target" />

      <Values>
        <Value AttributeID="PROJECTNO">P40841</Value>  <!-- Here -->
        <MultiValue AttributeID="TRADEMARKSTATEMENT">  <!-- Here -->
          <Value ID="SimpleABC">SimpleABC is a registered trademark</Value>
        </MultiValue>
        <Value AttributeID="DISCONTINUATIONREASON">PROD_PENDING_DISCONTINUE_REASON</Value>  <!-- Here -->
      </Values>
      <Product ID="ms750355" UserTypeID="MasterStock">
        <Name>14793MC</Name>
        <Values>
          <Value AttributeID="EBSExportFlag" ID="Y">Y</Value>  <!-- Here -->
        </Values>
        <Product ID="KIT781789" UserTypeID="KIT">
          <Name>14793P</Name>
          <Values>
            <Value AttributeID="STORAGEOPT">BLOCKS</Value>  <!-- Here -->
          </Values>
        </Product>
      </Product>
      <Product ID="ms750356" UserTypeID="MasterStock">
        <Name>14793MF</Name>
        <Values>
          <Value AttributeID="EBSExportFlag" ID="N">N</Value>  <!-- Here -->
        </Values>
        <Product ID="KIT781787" UserTypeID="KIT">
          <Name>14793BF</Name>
          <Values>
            <Value AttributeID="STORAGEOPT">SELF</Value>  <!-- Here -->
          </Values>
        </Product>
      </Product>
      <Product ID="pr801547" UserTypeID="Product_Revision">
        <Name>14793_rev1</Name>
          <ClassificationReference ClassificationID="pt213980" Type="Revision_to_ApplicationProtocol">
            <MetaData>
                            <MultiValue AttributeID="Appl_Species_Tested">  <!-- Here -->
                                <Value>All</Value>
                            </MultiValue>
                            <Value AttributeID="DILUTIONFACTOR">50</Value>  <!-- Here -->
                        </MetaData>
                    </ClassificationReference>
          <ProductCrossReference ProductID="ms750355" Type="ProductRevision_To_MasterStock" />
          <AssetCrossReference AssetID="14793W_0" Type="Published_Product_Images" />
        <Values>
          <Value AttributeID="RecombinantFlag_YN" ID="Y">Y</Value>  <!-- Here -->
        </Values>
      </Product>
    </Product>
  </Products>
</ROOT-ProductInformation>
```

Comment: you can use `//` For example `Values//Value` will match any node "Value" that is any descendant of of node "Values". Could you show a sample xml that is not matched properly

Comment: I have added an excerpt from the source document with values changed.  The "//" between Values and Value would not work as I only want to act on those that are: ...Values/Value...MultiValue... or MetaData/Value.  There are other "Value" elements in the doc that I do not want to alter.

Comment: There is no RootParent in this document. So I suppose you want `//Values/Value|//MultiValue|//MetaData/Value`

Comment: Do those other `Value` elements also have an `AttributeID` attribute? Otherwise you could simply use a predicate `Value[@AttributeID]`.

Comment: You are correct, I was using "RootParent" as a general term.  But yes, essentially what you have shown where the three combinations could be nested anywhere in the document.  Unfortunately adding still does not generate any output whereas it used to before the nesting.

Comment: Not all Value elements have an AttributeID attribute.  The XSLT needs to leave the ones alone that do not have an AttributeID attribute such as:    `<Value>9808S</Value>`  and act on only those that do.

Comment: The smallest sample file I have is over 4000 lines.  I'll pare it down and post it.  Thank you for your help so far.

Comment: I have updated the original question with a complete sample

Comment: And corrected it.  Ugh.

Comment: Using `//Values/Value|//MultiValue|//MetaData/Value` as @ArtemyVysotsky recommended works with my pared down file.  The larger file still does not convert so this is obviously a data problem.  Thanks @ArtemyVysotsky

Comment: You can test your xml and xslt at https://www.freeformatter.com/xsl-transformer.html

Comment: The current template match of `Values/Value|MultiValue|MetaData/Value` will match the elements at any level in the document, although you do need to remove `level="any"` from the `xsl:element` as the `level` attribute is not valid here. See http://xsltransform.net/93dEHGL to see it in action. The only issue I can see is that the XSLT is also removing the `AttributeID` attribute from the `AttributeLink` element (which is easily corrected if need be).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a different approach the transforms the elements `Value` and `MultiValue` having that attribute:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Change Value and MultiValue with @AttributeID -->
    <xsl:template match="Value[@AttributeID] | MultiValue[@AttributeID]">
      <xsl:element name="{@AttributeID}">
        <xsl:attribute name="OrgName">
          <xsl:value-of select="name()" />
        </xsl:attribute>      
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:element>        
    </xsl:template>

  <!--empty template suppresses this attribute-->
  <xsl:template match="Value/@AttributeID | MultiValue/@AttributeID" />

</xsl:transform>
```

http://xsltransform.net/bEzjRKN/1